git submodule下にあるファイルをimportできない: error TS2307: Cannot find module
aiueo > pack > kkk > index.tsの中に下記のような記載があります。
import { XXX } from './src/aaa';

ts2307 が出てしまい、モジュールを見つけられないです。
何かご教授頂けないでしょうか。
src は submodule になります。また、aiueo 配下は修正できないです。
フォルダ構成:


もし src ディレクトリの下に何もファイルがないなら、git submodule の pull が出来ていない可能性があります。git submodule update --init --recursive で submodule の内容も含めてローカルに持ってきてみてください。

ご回答ありがとうございます！ すみません、srcは空です。 ただ、どの階層でコマンド実行しても、取得できず…。
fatal: Failed to recurse into submodule path 'aiueo'

おそらく aiueo ディレクトリの中でサブモジュールを取得する形になろうと思います。それができないのであれば、何かしらサブモジュールの設定が壊れています。Failed to recurse into submodule path エラーの前に何が失敗しているのかのメッセージが表示されていると思うので、それを参照してみてください。

ありがとうございます。
結論、pathでエラー起こしてました。お騒がせしました。
